# Code not terminating when user prompts to N

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a password protected calculator. I'm having trouble with how I can ask the user if they want to continue or not. In case they want to continue, the calculator will show up again. The **'Y'** condition is working perfectly but **'N'** condition is also displaying the calculator again.

```
count=0
while count < 3:
    password = input('Enter password: ')
    if password=='HELLO123':
        print("Access Granted")
        print("Welcome to calculator program")
        number_1 = int(input('Enter your first number: '))
        number_2 = int(input('Enter your second number: '))
        print('{} + {} = '.format(number_1, number_2))
        print(number_1 + number_2)
        print('{} - {} = '.format(number_1, number_2))
        print(number_1 - number_2)
        print('{} * {} = '.format(number_1, number_2))
        print(number_1 * number_2)
        print('{} / {} = '.format(number_1, number_2))
        print(number_1 / number_2)
        while input("Do You Want To Continue? [y/n]") == "y" or "Y":
          print("Welcome to calculator program")
          number_1 = int(input('Enter your first number: '))
          number_2 = int(input('Enter your second number: '))
          print('{} + {} = '.format(number_1, number_2))
          print(number_1 + number_2)
          print('{} - {} = '.format(number_1, number_2))
          print(number_1 - number_2)
          print('{} * {} = '.format(number_1, number_2))
          print(number_1 * number_2)
          print('{} / {} = '.format(number_1, number_2))
          print(number_1 / number_2)
          break
    break
else:
        print('Access denied. Try again.')
        count += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with this line:

```
while input("Do You Want To Continue? [y/n]") == "y" or "Y":
```

The expression `input("Do You Want To Continue? [y/n]") == "y" or "Y"` is always `True`, because it is the same as `(input("Do You Want To Continue? [y/n]") == "y") or "Y"`. Since `"Y"` is not an empty string, it evaluates to `True` and `<anything> or True` evaluates to `True`.

Note that it also wouldn't work if the `or` bound more strongly than the `==`, since `input("Do You Want To Continue? [y/n]") == ("y" or "Y")` is the same as `input("Do You Want To Continue? [y/n]") == True` and that would always be `True` until you enter an empty string.

What you're looking for is:

```
while input("Do You Want To Continue? [y/n]") in ["y", "Y"]:
```

I wouldn't recommend coding your problem like this, but it will solve your immediate problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in the logic of your while loop. `while x == a or b:` will test if `x == a` or if `b`. In your case, this means that your second test is `"y"`, which evaluates to `True`, and as such your while loop never ends!

In order to check if the `input()` result is one of many potential results, you could use an `in` comparison to compare the result against an iterable such as a tuple:

```py
while input("Do You Want To Continue? [y/n]") in ("y", "Y"):
    print("Welcome to calculator program")
```